# Why is DbUpdateConcurrencyException thrown?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am using an SQL server and I have a table whose purpose is to hold a tree-like structure:

```
create table TableName (
   Id                   bigint               identity,
   Name                 nvarchar(50)         null,
   RootId               bigint               null,
   ParentId             bigint               null,
   Path                 nvarchar(100)        null,
   constraint PK_TableName primary key (Id)
)
```

The "Path" column value is generated by INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE trigger.
I am using EFCore 3.1 and each time I try to add a record into the table, I get DbUpdateConcurrencyException thrown.

What am I missing - how do I fix the problem?

btw, when I disable trigger insert passes and trigger works when I send regular INSERT command.

Thx Panagiotis for your answer. I understand the logic, but it still does not work. I have tried this:

```
protected virtual void MapTableName(EntityTypeBuilder<TableName> config)
{
    config.ToTable("TableName");
    config.HasKey(t => t.Id);
    config.Property(t => t.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().IsConcurrencyToken();
    config.Property(t => t.Name).IsConcurrencyToken().HasMaxLength(50);
    config.Property(t => t.Description).IsConcurrencyToken().HasMaxLength(100);
    config.Property(t => t.RootId).IsConcurrencyToken();
    config.Property(t => t.ParentId).IsConcurrencyToken();
    config.Property(t => t.Path).HasMaxLength(100).ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
    config.Property(t => t.TypeId).IsConcurrencyToken();
    config.Property(t => t.IsActive).IsConcurrencyToken();
    config.HasOne(t => t.LocationType).WithMany(t => t.TableNames).HasForeignKey(t => t.TypeId);
    config.HasOne(t => t.ParentTableName).WithMany(t => t.ChilTableNames).HasForeignKey(t => t.ParentId);
    config.HasOne(t => t.RootTableName).WithMany(t => t.ChildTableNamesAll).HasForeignKey(t => t.RootId);
}
```

but I get the same answer:

```
        "Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions."
```

Comment: Because EF thinks you're adding a new record, so it's expecting to see a value in @@IDENTITY. But it's not, because you are updating an existing record instead.

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi that's not what a *concurrency* exception is about

Comment: There are two things I can think of off the top of my head: move the trigger's logic into the application layer, or generate the SQL for the INSERT command, then execute it raw against the context.database.

Comment: I am pretty sure that since EF is expecting SaveChanges() to generate a new record, yet it sees no new records, it will assume a concurrency exception has occured.

Comment: The problem is the `Path`. EF Core uses optimistic concurrency by default, assuming that collisions (ie changes to the same record by another connection) are rare. To ensure the values haven't changed since a record was loaded, EF Core will check the value of a `rowversion` column if one exists, or compare *all* original property values against the table's values. If `Path` changes without EF knowing about it, it will appear there was a concurrency conflict

Comment: Ah okay makes sense.

Comment: The best way to fix this is to [add a `rowversion` column to the table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#add-optimistic-concurrency) and add it to the model with the `Timestamp` attribute (the old name for rowversion). In SQL Server, a rowversion is updated automatically by the server on every update. This way, only one small binary value is used for the concurrency check.

Comment: Another option is to [mark only a few of the properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations) with the [ConcurrencyCheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.concurrencycheckattribute?view=net-5.0) attribute. In this case, every property *except* `Path`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There are no concurrency checks when *adding* new record. The problem is apparently the trigger messing up the typical "auto-increment" logic of `insert into table values ...;  select Id from table where  @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity()` for retrieving the identity value. Hence the *"expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s)"* part of the error message (the rest of it is just misleading).

Comment: @IvanStoev there was no code at all when I posted the answer. Only the table schema, the name of the exception and the explanation that `Path` is modified due to triggers

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was just reading your comments :). But that explains them as well as the answer. Although even the original post explains the usage of 'instead of` trigger and that disabling it fixes the issue. The most confusing part of course is the misleading exception type/message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `Path`.

EF Core uses optimistic concurrency by default, assuming that collisions (ie changes to the same record by another connection) are rare. To ensure the values haven't changed since a record was loaded, EF Core will check the value of a `rowversion` column if one exists, or compare *all* original property values against the table's values. If `Path` changes without EF knowing about it, it will appear there was a concurrency conflict.

The best way to fix this is to [add a `rowversion` column to the table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#add-optimistic-concurrency) and add it to the model with the `Timestamp` attribute (the old name for rowversion). In SQL Server, a rowversion is updated automatically by the server on every update. This way, only one small binary value is used for the concurrency check :

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}

    public string Path {get;set;}

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

Another option is to [mark only a few of the properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations) with the [ConcurrencyCheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.concurrencycheckattribute?view=net-5.0) attribute. In this case, every property *except* `Path` :

```
{
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public string Name{get;set;}

    public string Path {get;set;}
}
```